# Grid-Stride Loop in cuda and matrix operations, why do we need it?

Tags: c, cuda

```
__global__ void substract(float *A, float *B, float *res, int *n)
{
    int size = *n;
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    while (tid < size) 
    {
        res[tid] = A[tid] - B[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}


int function(...) {
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocks = (n+threadsPerBlock-1)/threadsPerBlock;
    int blocksPerGrid = 32<blocks ? 32 : blocks;
.
.
.
    substract<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(A, B, res, n);
.
.
.
}
```

So I wrote this code that takes an array `A` that represents a matrix of size `n`x`n` and a second array `B` that represents the vector of size `n` and I  subtract one from the other. Let's say the size of this array is 1000x1000. I wrote it kind of by following the examples on multiple cuda guides, but I can't understand why we need this part: `tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;`

Since it will never fit as array id element, it will always be larger than or equal to 1024 and my array only has 0-999 id's, it seems useless to me, but without it my program crashes, the screen turns black and after a few seconds it returns and I get the pop up that drivers have recovered. So I tried to understand why I can't just go through the whole array with the `tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;`. I printed all the `tid`s before the `while` loop and it seems it just goes all the way from 0 to 1024 in random order since it can't count on `tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;` to  calculate anything inside my array boundaries I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If your array size  is equal to or smaller than your grid size, then the grid stride loop doesn't provide much benefit in that case.  It is particularly useful when the array size is bigger than the grid size, or when you want to write a kernel that can flexibly handle arbitrary array sizes, without having to adjust your grid size.

However the grid-stride addition code may still be needed if your array size is less than or equal to the grid size.  The reason for this will become evident if you think carefully about your while-loop: this addition operation is needed to cause the while-loop to terminate on all threads.

Suppose your array size is 1024 and it is equal to your grid size of 1024 threads (whether all in one block or not; doesn't matter).

Initially your threads will have `tid` indices of 0-1023.  none of these values cause the while loop to terminate. If the while loop never terminates, your kernel will hang and run forever until or unless you have a kernel timeout (which is what you are seeing).

But with the addition statement, after the first while-loop iteration, each thread has a `tid` value of 1024 or greater, which will cause the while loop to terminate for all threads (assuming `size` is 1024 or less).

Comment: That makes sense but there's one thing that bothers me. I tried to remove the tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x; part and replace the while loop with the same if statement with the same condtion so it wouldn't need the 'stride' anymore to terminate the loop. But now the execution is about 50-60 ms slower than it used to be with while and the tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x; (i ran the program a few times to make sure that it's not some random event). Makes me wonder why it's faster if with this grid size it should be useless.

Comment: That seems like a different question to me.  It's a performance question now.  It would be useful to see both codes in their entirety, and to identify the method you are using to determine timing, and other details such as the exact compile command line, the OS, and the GPU you are running on.  That's a lot that would completely turn this question into something else; therefore I suggest you ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Also note that your code as written here is only going to subtract the vector from the first "row" of the matrix (I'm not really sure what matrix-vector "subtraction" should be, but if that was your intent - then great.)